# new firebase update: popup window for Google Auth does not show up in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I recently updated to the new firebase that just came out a few days ago. Since it does not have a Cordova/Ionic special page, I assume that I would need to use the one for Web. I got everything set up, but the  signInWithPopup function does not work on actual phone device. It works fine in web browser. I have whitelisted firebase before for the previous version and everything was working just fine for the previous version.Does anyone have any idea? Any help with be appreciated it!

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
 // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
var token = result.credential.accessToken;
// The signed-in user info.
var user = result.user;
//  ...
}).catch(function(error) {
// Handle Errors here.
var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;
// The email of the user's account used.
var email = error.email;
// The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
var credential = error.credential;
// ...
});
```

Here is what's in my content security policy

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content=" img-src &apos;self&apos; data:
                                                                                     http://*.google.com
                       http://*.gstatic.com
                       http://*.googleapis.com
                       http://*.firebaseio.com
                       https://*.google.com
                       https://*.gstatic.com
                       https://*.googleapis.com
                       https://*.firebaseio.com
```

Finally I allowed naviagation for everything in my config.xml

```
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: thanks Raymond for asking, I don't see any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup and redirect doesnt work on mobile device. You may need to use cordovaOauth or any other 3rd party to get the access token, and then use signInWithCredential() to authenticate users and get the firebase user data.

Here is a good example:
http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/firebase-3-0-ionic-facebook-login

Answer (score 0):

Currently Firebaseu V3 auth's signInWithPopup/Redirect do not work in cordova apps.

Answer (score 0):

In my **Ionic2 RC1 + Firebase3.5 + AngularFire2.beta5** project I had the same problem... Google Auth with Popup worked in Browser but not in my Android .APK

Firstly, I add *192.168.1.172* to my Firebase Console authorized domain list and `<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.172:8100"/>` to my *config.xml*.

After this, I found that **[installing Cordova InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html#installation)** plugin solves my problem definitively.

I didn't need to modify my code, only plug and play, exactly like David East says in his [Social login with Ionic blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/social-login-with-ionic_77.html).